# Are cards that are both Land and Creature affected by summoning sickness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are cards that are both Land and Creature affected by summoning sickness with regard to:

1. Possibility to attack
2. Activating special abilities with the TAP symbol?

Comment: Some relevant cards: [Dryad Arbor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136196), [Life and Limb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=124471).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes they are affected. No they cannot use any ability that requires {T} or {Q} as part of the cost (unless the land creature also has haste).

---

[Dryad Arbor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=145391) satisfies the criteria for being a creature. (or [Charmille dryade](http://www.magiccorporation.com/gathering-cartes-view-13479-charmille-dryade.html) in French)

> 205.2b Some objects have more than one card type (for example, an artifact creature). Such objects satisfy the criteria for any effect that applies to any of their card types.

**Creatures** cannot activate abilities that require {T} or {Q}.

> 107.5. The tap symbol is {T}. The tap symbol in an activation cost means “Tap this permanent.” A permanent that’s already tapped can’t be tapped again to pay the cost. A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. See rule 302.6.
>
> 107.6. The untap symbol is {Q}. The untap symbol in an activation cost means “Untap this permanent.” A permanent that’s already untapped can’t be untapped again to pay the cost. A creature’s activated ability with the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. See rule 302.6.

**Creatures** cannot attack if you haven't controlled them since the start of their most recent turn.

> 302.6. A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. A creature can’t attack unless it has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the “summoning sickness” rule.

Unless they have **Haste**, a **Creature** cannot attack or activate abilities that require {T} or {Q} in their cost.

> 702.10b If a creature has haste, it can attack even if it hasn’t been controlled by its controller continuously since his or her most recent turn began. (See rule 302.6.)
>
> 702.10c If a creature has haste, its controller can activate its activated abilities whose cost includes the tap symbol or the untap symbol even if that creature hasn’t been controlled by that player continuously since his or her most recent turn began. (See rule 302.6.)

Comment: Regular lands can give mana with {T}, and the card I wonder on has a special ability to give a green mana when it'is tapped. As it is also a land, can I tap it for mana ?

Comment: @sinsedrix, Dryad Arbor is most likely the card you are talking about. Dryad Arbor has "Land Creature" in the Type Line. You can {T} if for green mana, but because it is a creature, you cannot do so unless you have controlled it since the start of your turn (or it has haste). My answer covers the general case, as well as your particular case. What is this card you are asking about, if it isn't Dryad Arbor?

Comment: To be sure (as my english is not great), in fact the creature nature of the card prevails on its land nature and I cannot tap it (even for mana) in the first turn it comes into play? I only have the french card but the translation seems to correspond to "Dryad Arbor".

Comment: @sinsedrix,I am certain that your English is better than my French. "Charmille dryade" is Dryad Arbor. Because it is a creature, all effects, abilities, and other cards that care if Dryad Arbor is a creature, (its creature nature will prevail). Because it is a land, all effects, abilities, and other cards that care if Dryad Arbor is a land, (its land nature will prevail). Dryad Arbor's creature type does not prevent it from having the Forest ability, "{T}: Ajoutez {G} à votre réserve". Neither does Dryad Arbor's land type prevent it from being subject to summoning sickness(le mal d'invocation)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are affected. If you play a land and transform it, summoning sickness applies as if you cast a creature directly.

You can find a similar question in the [MTG Salvation forum](http://forums.mtgsalvation.com/showthread.php?t=372709).

Edit: This is true for attacking as well as using special abilities that require you to tap the creature.

Comment: What about special abilities?

Comment: Exactly the same. I will add this to my answer.

Comment: Though regular lands can give mana as soon as they are played, and the card I wonder on has a special ability to give a green mana when it'is tapped.

Comment: Note that a creature has summoning sickness if it was not under your control at the beginning of the turn, not only if you played it this turn.

Comment: Hackworth: Does that mean that a creature I capture using "enslave" has summoning sickness?

Comment: Sinsedrix: Which card are you talking about. Discussion will be easier if we know the card in question.

Comment: *302.6. A creature's activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can't be activated **unless the creature has been under its controller's control continuously since his or her most recent turn began**. A creature can't attack unless it has been under its controller's control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the "summoning sickness" rule.* Thats why cards like Threaten give the creature haste.